# Xcode 6.1 won't let me access CloudKit Dashboard

Tags: icloud, dashboard, cloudkit

After everything had been set up for CloudKit, with provisioning profiles and CloudKit container set up, I still get the message,

```
There are no CloudKit enabled apps associated with this AppleID. Contact your team administrator...
```

when trying to access the Dashboard. I had previously tried everything, from renaming my entire project to making sure I was signed into *iCloud* before trying. All of the 'check boxes' were checked in the *iCloud* part of the *Capabilities* section.

The solution, as it turns out, is that only *team administrators* themselves can access the *Dashboard*. My professor made an *administrator* and it worked. I never explicitly saw this anywhere on posts or in Apple documentation.

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message in cloudKit dashboard, it turned out I was logged in with a different appleID.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the bundleID and containerID you point to must all be consistent with the Container name.

Comment: What?! Bundle ID, container ID and Name?! This is completely untrue. Examples: For Bundle ID (app ID): `com.apple.TextEdit` the container ID would be (by default) `iCloud.com.apple.TextEdit` and the container name may **not** contain periods (`.`) You see it can't be true?